# Why debugger lldb says object is nil in iOS 5.1 simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios5, lldb

My write some code like:

```
_myDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity : kNum];

for (int i=0; i<kNum; i++) {
    MyData *myData = [[[MyData alloc] init] autorelease];
    pageData.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No.%d line", i];
    [_myDataArray addObject:myData];
}
```

There is no problem in iOS 4.3 simulator, but lldb debugger says _myDataArray is nil

```
(lldb) po _myDataArray
(NSMutableArray *) $2 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

in iOS 5.0/5.1 simulator, Xcode 4.3.1 but result of in view is correct.

Xcode 4.3.2 looks fix this problem.

Comment: at what point does lldb say _myDataArray is nil?  if you do `NSLog( @"_myDataArray is %p", _myDataArray);` within the code, does it also appear as nil?  Are you using ARC?  What's `kNum` defined as?

Comment: NSLog print _myDataArray is not nil. I find problem is: I create instance variable NSMutableArray *_myPageDataArray in .h file, that's not right. I should create it in .m file.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I've just run in to this, and tried moving the variable definition into the m file, but it doesn't do the trick.  Something seems seriously wrong.

Comment: MagicSeth try to set the variable to @private

Comment: Xcode 4.3.2 looks fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that we have the same problem with the 5.0 and 5.1 simulator using the 4.3.1 Xcode.  Same code with Xcode 4.2.1 and 5.0 simulator doesn't have the problem. Noticed that mutable arrays getting allocated in the order they are in the .h file - stepping through the .m code in debug mode is hilarious because arrays are getting allocated out of order.  Solution? Wait for Apple to fix the problem, report the bug, etc.

Comment: try to set the variable to @private

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the exact same problem with iOS 4.3, 5.0 and 5.1 both on iDevice and in the Simulator. An Update from Xcode 4.3.1 to 4.3.2 does not solve the problem here...

Switching back to the GDB debugger in the scheme settings solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with all of my projects in the 5.0 and 5.1 simulators.  XCode 4.3.3 fixed this for me.